# Can we have an HTML audio player (<audio>) with same appearance/styling in all browsers?

Tags: html

Currently, I've observed that the audio player added via HTML  tag looks different in appearance in Chrome and Firefox.
[image]

Is there any standard we can follow to make its appearance same across browsers or implement custom player in an easy way to achieve the purpose?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we can have customised audio player which can look same across all the browsers. But the thing is we need to do styling and develope functionality of that audio player like

1. a play/pause button
2. a seek slider
3. the current time indicator
4. the duration of the sound file
5. a way to mute the audio
6. a volume control slider.

May be the following article will help you

https://css-tricks.com/lets-create-a-custom-audio-player/

Answer (score 0):

Yea You can have it.

You Just Need to write the Appearance `.css` for all platform **Respectively And Explicitly**